# Preact component not rendering elements inside loop

Tags: reactjs, jsx, tsx, preact

I have a Preact component which should render an array. The array is not multidimensional; I'm mapping a 2D array to a 1D array (so I can't just `.map()`). Anyway, it is only rendering the parent `div` but is still iterating correctly when debugging.

```
export const Grid = ({ width, height }: { width: number, height: number }) => {
    const [grid] = useState<Cell[]>(initialiseArray({ width, height, fill: () => ({ active: Math.random() < 0.5 }) }));

    return (
        <div>
            {[...Array(width)].map((_, indexX) =>
                {
                    {[...Array(height)].map((_, indexY) => (
                            <div style={{ backgroundColor: grid[indexX * height + indexY].active ? "red" : "white" }}>
                                X
                            </div>
                        )
                    )}
                }
            )}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Which is simply returning `<div></div>`. What's wrong here?

Comment: The outer map doesn’t return anything.

Comment: Can you expand on that?

Answer (score 0):

The outer map doesn't return anything.

When you use `.map(() => { ... })` (emphasis on the curly braces), you need to explicitly `return` a value. For example:

```
const x = foo.map(() => {
    <div>foo</div>
});
```

`x` in this example will be empty, but either of the following will fix this:

```
const x = foo.map(() => {
    return <div>foo</div>
});

const x = foo.map(() =>
    <div>foo</div>
);
```

So you need to either add in `return` or remove the curly braces (`{}`).

```
export const Grid = ({ width, height }: { width: number; height: number }) => {
  const [grid] = useState<Cell[]>(initialiseArray({ width, height, fill: () => ({ active: Math.random() < 0.5 }) }));

  return (
    <div>
-     {[...Array(width)].map((_, indexX) => {
+     {[...Array(width)].map((_, indexX) => (
        {
          [...Array(height)].map((_, indexY) => (
            <div
              style={{
                backgroundColor: grid[indexX * height + indexY].active
                  ? "red"
                  : "white",
              }}
            >
              X
            </div>
          ));
        }
-     })}
+     ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```